# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n\phi)}{n}$ where $0<\phi<\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n\phi)}{n}$ where $0<\phi<\pi$

From advance calculus I learn that , I need to find the partial sum and stuff. But from complex analysis class, my professor told me that I can turn this into integral form, but he didn't tell me how.

I wonder if anyone please show me how to turn this to integral form.

Comment: Hint,$\cos(n\phi)=\dfrac{e^{ni\phi}+e^{-ni\phi}}{2}$

Comment: but how do I turn that into integral form?

Comment: I don't know what your professor means by "integral form", but both Olivier and I have derived the "closed form" for the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** One may recall that
$$
-\log (1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n}}{n}, \quad |z|<1,
$$
giving, for $0<\phi<\pi$,
$$
\begin{align} \tag{1}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n\phi)}{n}&=\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in\phi}}{n}\\\\ \tag{2}
&=-\Re\:\log (1-e^{i\phi})\\\\ \tag{3a}
&=-\Re\:\log \left(-e^{i\phi/2}\left(e^{i\phi/2}-e^{-i\phi/2}\right)\right)\\\\ \tag{3b}
&=-\Re\:\log \left(-2ie^{i\phi/2}\sin (\phi/2)\right)\\\\ \tag{3c}
&=-\Re\:\log \left(2e^{i(\phi/2-\pi/2)}\sin ( \phi/2)\right)\\\\ \tag{4}
&=-\log \left(2 \sin ( \phi/2)\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: sure, thank you very much, for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\phi)}{n}
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in\phi}}{n}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-in\phi}}{n}\\
&=-\frac12\log(1-e^{i\phi})-\frac12\log(1-e^{-i\phi})\\
&=-\frac12\log(2-2\cos(\phi))\\
&=-\frac12\log(4\sin^2(\phi/2))\\[6pt]
&=-\log(2\sin(\phi/2))
\end{align}
$$
This is valid for $0\lt\phi\le\pi$ because we used $\sqrt{\sin^2(\phi/2)}=\sin(\phi/2)$. However, if we use $\sqrt{\sin^2(\phi/2)}=|\sin(\phi/2)|$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\phi)}{n}
=-\log(2|\sin(\phi/2)|)
$$
which is valid for $-\pi\le\phi\le\pi$ except for $\phi=0$.

Comment: I use your method to compute another series, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199738/compute-sum-n-0-infty-frac-sin-2n1-phi2n1-for-0-phi-pi/1199815?noredirect=1#1199823, but it doesn't work. I understand your method better than use $\Im$ stuff, so I wonder if you would check to see what wrong with my work please.

Comment: I will look, but I am tied up until after 6:30 PM PDT.

Comment: What is wrong with that answer?

Comment: my answer? I can't simplify further, and other people say I did something wrong, but I don't know what did I do wrong

Comment: Oh, you're asking about your question. You linked one of the answers, so I thought that was what you were asking about. I have added an answer. It is more to the point of what you were doing wrong; I don't compute the sum since Jack does that using the same method.

Comment: yeah, I got it now, thank you very much

Comment: Okay, I only answered because I said I would comment. If Jack has a problem with me covering the same point, I will remove my answer.